# SQL Server Multi-Step Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've got a software suite that is based off of multiple libraries where:

1 library = 1 SQL Database.

Different users can have different access to different libraries.

In addition, the databases are named in a specific manner to help identify which are "mine" and which aren't.

I'd like to create a stored procedure that takes a variable called `@UserName` and returns the databases that have a name starting with `MYDB`, where `@UserName` is found in a table `USERS`.

I'm figuring that I'll start with `EXEC sp_databases`, but I'm unsure how to continue.

What I need to know is:

1. How do I iterate the results of sp_databases to pull out just the databases that have a name matching my pattern?
2. How do I then check for `@UserName` in the `[USER NAME]` column of the `USERS` table of each database returned from #1?

I'm guessing it has something to do with temp tables and cursors, but I'm not really sure where to start.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some proof of concept code to show you an approach. sys.databases contains a more accessible list of databases. You'll pretty much have to use dynamic sql at some point though.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyDBs @userName VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @max INT
DECLARE @i INT 
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(500)

CREATE TABLE #SQL
(
    rid int identity primary key clustered,
    query varchar(500)
)

INSERT INTO #SQL(query)
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ['+ name '+].USERS WHERE username = @UserName'
FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE NAME LIKE '%yourpattern%'

SELECT @max = @@rowcount, @i = 1

WHILE @i <= @max
BEGIN
     SELECT @sql = query FROM #sql WHERE rid = @i
     EXEC @sql
     SET @i = @i + 1
END 

DROP TABLE #SQL
```

Comment: I ended up with a slightly modified version of this, but you definitely got me on the right track! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For 1, just look at the sp_databases code, **copy it** and modify it to your needs. For Example (see last 2 conditions of where clause. This is the actual code of the sp_databases stored proc. You can look at it on the master db):

```
declare @UserName varchar(50)='someuser'
select
        DATABASE_NAME   = db_name(s_mf.database_id),
        DATABASE_SIZE   = convert(int,
                                    case -- more than 2TB(maxint) worth of pages (by 8K each) can not fit an int...
                                    when convert(bigint, sum(s_mf.size)) >= 268435456
                                    then null
                                    else sum(s_mf.size)*8 -- Convert from 8192 byte pages to Kb
                                    end),
        REMARKS         = convert(varchar(254),null)
    from
        sys.master_files s_mf
    where
        s_mf.state = 0 and -- ONLINE
        has_dbaccess(db_name(s_mf.database_id)) = 1 and
        --db_name(s_mf.database_id) like '%'+@UserName+'%' and exists -- you may or may not want to leave this condition here. You'll figure out what condition to use
        (select 1 from databasename.dbo.Users where [UserName]=@UserName)
    group by s_mf.database_id
     order by 1
```